# Getting Perforce Connection Error with invalid SSL session

Tags: perforce

Getting the following error while trying to create a new perforce connection with helix client for eclipse

Error occurred during SSL handshake: invalid SSL session

I have tried replacing the JCE with the Unlimited JCE Policy as I have found in several articles.

Comment: What is your P4PORT setting? Are you connecting successfully with the `p4` command line using that value as `p4 -p $P4PORT info`?

Comment: Yes. I am only getting problem with perforce eclipse plugin.